# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowBackground'

Tags: android, android-styles

As it is said in this [doc](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) I am using items in values/styles.xml without "android" namespace and in values-v14/styles.xml with "android" namespace. But when building values/styles.xml it says"No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowBackground'."

here is the code for values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyDefaultStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowBackground">@color/list_app_background</item>
</style>
```

here is the code for values-v14/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyDefaultStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/list_app_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because the windowBackground is from api 21 so u should use it on

values-v21

Comment: Do you know if there's any support for this in the compatibility library, and if so how I use it? It's kind-of annoying that you can't change the window background colour without needing to use Android 5!

Comment: yes, but I don't remember which attribute was and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate a new project and import the forms and units.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).