# Changing background colour of activities themed using the AppCompat themes in older Android versions

Tags: android, themes, android-support-library

I am using the following theme for my application:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I would like to change the background colour.  In order to do so, according to the documentation I can add the following to the theme definition:

```
    <item name="windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
```

Unfortunately, however, this only compiles correctly if (as suggested in the answer at [No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowBackground'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349495/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-windowbackground)) I restrict it to being applied to Android versions with API 21 or higher.

How I can I make this work on earlier versions of Android?  I would ideally like to specify a background colour for Android versions down to API 16, which is my current minimum.

Comment: `android:windowBackground` was added in [API 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowBackground). What makes you think it only works on API 21 or higher?

Comment: @ianhanniballake - the fact that I was using just "windowBackground" not "android:windowBackground", which led to the answer I linked to which stated that API 21 was required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true as you said that `windowBackground` so you will just need to replace it with `android:windowBackground` that is for API 14 and higher

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
```

to **../values-v21/styles.xml**

Answer (score 0):

```
 //   Your Problem is that You are use Theme.Appcompat then extends ActionBarActivity

if you use AppcompatActivity then use

 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
```